grpc Greeter Service sample fails randomly
I came across a problem with grpc sample code while I was testing waters with it. I noticed that client succeeds, let's say 75% of time but fails at a rate of 25% with following error:
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
        details = "Method not found!"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {grpc_message:"Method not found!", grpc_status:12, created_time:"2024-06-12T10:16:43.243776013+03:00"}"

Please see the picture attached.

I'd expect it to work 100% of the time. What am I missing here ?
Please note that, I haven't made any changes to the sample code. I am using them as is and I got them via:
git clone -b v1.64.0 --depth 1 --shallow-submodules https://github.com/grpc/grpc

EDIT
My environment for this example:
Host OS : Linux (Manjaro)
Network : Client and server are both running on the same machine, just different terminal windows.
Firewall Rules: 
python --version                                                                                                                   
Python 3.12.3

pip freeze
grpcio==1.64.1
grpcio-tools==1.64.1
protobuf==5.27.1
setuptools==70.0.0


It's very difficult to debug non-reproducible errors via Stack overflow. Your question also lacks some of the details that may provide someone with experience with similar errors to help you. You don't describe the host OS, network configuration, python, gRPC library versions etc.The only guidance that we can realistically provide (unless this is a known issue with specific versions of the software) is to ensure that you're running the latest versions of everything.

My bad. I added as much details as I could. If you think I am missing something, please let me know. Thank you @DazWilkin for your reply.

My comment wasn't a criticism so no apology is necessary but thank you. Thanks for adding more details.

Your configuration is good. Checking GitHub issues for you.

Please add logs from the server process too

Server process does not spit out anything.

I won't be able to try to repro this before tomorrow. I didn't see anything regards obvious issues with the latest gRPC builds (which was unlikely). It would be interesting to see whether you can trigger the error. It may be a connection|concurrency issue (unsure). Perhaps while true; do python greeter_client.py; sleep 15s; done and vary sleep X until you can reliably trigger the error. If that doesn't work, change the client to loop/sleep over the gRPC method call.

weird. I tried to reproduce the problem to double check that server side does not log anything, I can't seem to generate the error. I tried may be 20 times and so far so good.I will keep trying more and let you know.

To be clear, your assumption that this should (!?) work without issue is correct. I've been using gRPC for many years (former Googler) and, in my experience, gRPC is very reliable. So, my suspicion is that this is probably something in your (networking) config.

Looks like it is working solid now. I really have no idea why it was failing earlier. Thank you so much for your time but please do not waste it any more as I can not seem to reproduce the error. I haven't changed anything at all. :\ Oh. I rebooted my machine. Would it make any difference ? I don't know for sure.

Thank you so much for your time @DazWilkin . I do appreciate it.

It's possible that, by rebooting, you've enabled more recent versions of software. It will also have reset e.g. operating system, network state etc. So you may have flushed the bad out. This demonstrates the difficulty in debugging non-reproducible errors.

Thanks again for your time @DazWilkin. Much appreciated
